# Using REACT ROUTER 4 nested Routes are coming blank

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using React and React-Router-V4, as I am new to React and was wondering if theres anything I am missing out.

When I go to route "/" it works and displays `Index` component but when i go to "/posts/index" it does not show me anything, not even a `DefaultPage` component, following are my routes inside `index.js`:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/posts/index' component={ShowPosts} />
    <Route path='/' component={Index} />
    <Route component={DefaultPage} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Is your server setup to respond with your app when you request "/posts/index"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can't comment, I believe problem is with `webpack.config.js` and not `react-router` as you may not have a `/` inside, if you give Public path to the output hopefully that will be fine.

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'webpack-index.js',
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

Comment: That was the issue and now its sorted THANKS !

Answer (score 1):

first you need to add `exact` to index Route, or your default page Route will not work if the URL path wrong.

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Index} />
```

and about ShowPosts route it look like the error from the component, share your component code if possible.